# Rails: validation on blog comments not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to learn Rails by building a simple blog. I have made it possible to add comments with AJAX en I am now trying to validate the presence of a name and body in the comments. However, the validation is not working. When there are no errors the comment gets added like it should, but when I leave either 'name' or 'body' blank and try to add the comment, I get redirected to this weird flat HTML-version of the post I was trying to comment on (with a path like this: /posts/21/comments). I do not understand why this is happening instead of just the post page reappearing with an error message in it, and I would be very grateful to anyone that could help me out.

So here is the CommentsController:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
        if @comment.errors.any?
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { render @post }
                format.js
            end
        else
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html { redirect_to @post }
                format.js
            end
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @post }
            format.js
        end
    end

    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  validates_presence_of :body, :name
end
```

And comment part of show.html.erb:

```
<section id="comment-section">
  <div id="comments">
    <h2>Reacties</h2>
    <%= render partial: @post.comments.reverse %>
  </div>

  <%= form_for [@post, Comment.new], remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
    <% if @comment && @comment.errors.any? %>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name, "Naam" %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :name %></br></br>

      <%= f.label :body, "Reactie" %><br/>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Verstuur" %></p>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

And the _comment.html.erb partial:

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
  <p>
    <strong>
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
    </strong>
    <br/>
    <i><%= comment.name %>:</i>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <% if logged_in? %>
      <%= button_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
               :method => :delete,
               :class=> 'link-button',
               remote: true,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
                %>
    <% end %>

  </p>
<% end %>
```

Finally, my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/aboutme'
  get 'static_pages/photos'

  get 'sessions/new'

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  get    'admin'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'admin'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/overmij' => 'static_pages#aboutme'
  get '/fotos' => 'static_pages#photos'

  root 'posts#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this line `format.html { render @post }` That line renders the `comments.index` as they are nested with in posts so you get `post/:id/comments`. If you want to render a view (from another controller) you have to do it like this:

```
render template "posts/show"
```

or just

```
render "posts/show"
```

But the thing about rendering a view/template is that it will not set any variables needed, so you'll get a error like `@variable is nil` so you need to set the variables needed for post/show. Another thing you can do is `redirect_to @post` but the thing about redirect is that it will refresh the page and erase what the user had typed in the text box.

These are rails [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) on rendering/redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use flash to display my error messages, something like this should work

Controller

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html { flash[:notice] = @comment.errors, render @post }
 format.js
end
```

View

```
<%if notice.present? %>
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
   <% notice.each do |msg| %>
   <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it gives a weird syntax error, and it still makes me wonder why my own 'render @post' didn't just bring me to '/post/id'